# How can I make this Function Based View work?

Tags: python, html, django

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class RoomDetail(DetailView):

    """ RoomDetail Definition """

    model = models.Room

........
#omitted
........


@login_required
def delete_room(request, room_pk):

    user = request.user
    user_pk = user.pk
    try:
        room = models.Room.objects.get(pk=room_pk)
        if room.host.pk != user.pk:
            messages.error(request, "Can't delete the Room")
        else:
            room.delete()
            messages.success(request, "Room Deleted")
        return redirect(reverse("users:profile", kwargs={"pk": user_pk}))
    except models.Room.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect(reverse("core:home"))
```

users/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    .......
    #omitted
    .......


    path("<int:pk>/", views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name="profile"),
]
```

html

```
........
<-- omitted -->
........


<div class="mt-1 mb-3 sm:my-0 w-full sm:w-1/3">
    {% if room.host == user %}
    <a href="{% url 'rooms:edit' room.pk %}" class="btn-link block mb-3 bg-green-500">Edit Room</a>
    <a href="{% url 'rooms:delete' room.pk %}" class="btn-link block">Delete Room</a>
    <div class="w-full text-center">
      <span class="font-extrabold mx-auto mt-px text-yellow-600" >WARNING!!! THIS ACTION IS NOT RETRIEVABLE!!</span>
    </div>
      
    {% endif %}
</div>

...........
<-- omitted -->
...........
```

In the code above, I've tried to make "Delete Room" anchor function, whose function is deleting room and redirect users to their profile, if they are the owner of the room. But clicking that "Delete Room' didn't function as I expected, just turning back the error below to me. And I don't understand why the error is about "unexpected keyword argument". In my knowledge, it is required because the url I want to redirect users need the keyword argument "<int:pk>". What is wrong in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

error

```
TypeError at /rooms/176/delete/
delete_room() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rooms/176/delete/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
delete_room() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
Exception Location: C:\Users\josep\.virtualenvs\Airbnb-Clone-GrEkW6GP\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py in _wrapped_view, line 21
Python Executable:  C:\Users\josep\.virtualenvs\Airbnb-Clone-GrEkW6GP\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\josep\\Documents\\nomad academy\\Airbnb-Clone',
 'c:\\users\\josep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\josep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\josep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\josep\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'C:\\Users\\josep\\.virtualenvs\\Airbnb-Clone-GrEkW6GP',
 'C:\\Users\\josep\\.virtualenvs\\Airbnb-Clone-GrEkW6GP\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 24 Dec 2020 23:04:23 +0900
```

Comment: Apparently the URL parameter is `pk`, not `room_pk`, so it should be `def delete_room(request, pk):`...

Comment: But that being said, you should *not* delete/update/create `Room`s with a GET request: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipatterns/a_get_request_with_side_effects.html

Comment: Your help was very effective! I changed room_pk to pk, and I made a form that uses post method. Additionally, I found room.pk in html should be changed to pk. In result, that is fixed now! Thanks for your comments :)